# Execute command from REST API in ACI

Tags: azure, websocket, azure-container-instances

I'm trying to figure out how to run a command in an Azure Container Instance via the REST API. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/containers/execute-command?view=rest-container-instances-2023-05-01&tabs=HTTP)

I can POST and get the WSS URL and password, but connecting then sending the password along returns `>` in HEX. I can decode some of the HEX sent from postman, and it's just the command I sent given back to me in binary.

I am trying to run `rcon-cli` which in theory returns a shell in which I can run commands to my app. However, due to the above 'command echoing' as I'm dubbing it, nothing happens. Is there any docs out there on this WebSocket server? Thank you!

I have tried the following:

- Using `application/json`, to no avail. It simply uses application/octet-stream, which is expected.
- Omitting the terminal size query parameter from the WSS URL. Unsure why there is a terminal size parameter in the first place.
- Encoding what I send in HEX.
- Creating a simple plain JS webapp

Here is a screenshot from postman of me trying to send the password. Sometimes it'll send me a `>`, sometimes it does nothing.

[image: postman]

Comment: Are you doing it via Postman?

Comment: The end goal is to do it programmatically. I am trying to test via Postman so I know how it works

Comment: So postman call is working fine?

Comment: It is not. It does the same "command echoing" and I get nothing useful from it

Comment: Can you paste the screenshot of postman when you call the API?

Comment: I can. I'll update the post shortly